# Question about powering ADC to LED board

Tags: power-supply, power

My bench power supply died today & I thought I'd salvage the LED displays. Turns out they are on a board which has 2 x [ICL7107 3 1/2 digit A/D converters](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/ICL7106-ICL7107.pdf). The datasheet says that the max supply V +6v but also mentions -9V. Does this mean the chips need a dual supply?

I noticed that the board has a [L7805CV positive voltage regulator](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/389/cd00000444-1795274.pdf) which according to the data sheet gives a 5V output. Prior to this there is a [2w10 bridge rectifier](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/139/2W10-pdf.php).

So my assumption here is that I can power this from a +5V supply if take out the regulator & the bridge?

[image][image]

Comment: check where it says that. I only found 9V specifically in reference to a **different** IC than the one you have in that datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 9:

the PDF is a scanned image here's a paste of a screenshot as I can't copy text:

[image]

so to run off a single supply you can use figure 18:

[image]
I'm guessing they're done something like that, perhaps using a resistor only reference as I don't see any diodes on that board.

Comment: Yes after examining the board they've set it up like fig 18 without the diodes